# Could not open the editor: Editor could not be initialized

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, adobe

Happy New year everyone!Have a healthy and prosperous 2010!

Now for the question that I have :
I am getting error `"Could not open the editor: Editor could not be initialized."` 
when i try to open the CF3 builder.

Neglecting this error I am continuing with my work and  I am able to access all my project/files etc ,but what i feel is that it is damn slow and have an hunch that i might be wrong somewhere.

So was looking for this ".project" file.I found 
I have this ".project" file in my workspace folder , but it is not showing in the CF builder 3.

How to correct the error?
`"Could not open the editor: Editor could not be initialized."Is the error related to the "add Project" or ".project" file in the workspace?
PS:-
is there any documentation for how to add a "project/workspace" in CF builder3 ?

Answer (score 4):

Think "File > Import > General > Import existing project" is what you need.

P.S. "CF Builder beta 3", please.

Comment: I restarted my System and the error seem to go away!Thanks Sergii!